# Trying to pass different values to openMp thread in its thread function parameter

Tags: c, openmp

I have this code that I am trying to figure out how to pass different value to as thread parameter in openMp threads

So for example I have an simple decrement statement like --t where t is a variable so every time thread function called it gets decremented value of t first then is received as thread parameter. this is what I tried

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int t=2;
    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(t=(--t))
    {
        
        printf("%d\n",t);
    }
    
    // Ending of parallel region
}
```

So I have absolute no clue how this above code is expended to since I assumed `firstprivate(...)` part of #pragma omp directive is just a way of spawning a thread using open mp but I need different parameters received each thread. Is it doable in openMM C

Comment: also it will be awesome if someone give me info on some sort of shared variable in openmp that add values of in threads parameters with each other like addition of first thread parameter with second thread parameter and so on in shared variable of openMp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do that in a `firstprivate` clause. However, you can change the clause to `shared` and use the **`atomic` construct** to *update* the value safely. Here is an example:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int t=2;

    #pragma omp parallel shared(t)
    {
        int local_t_value;

        #pragma omp atomic capture relaxed
        local_t_value = --t;

        printf("%d\n", local_t_value);
    }
}
```

Note that `capture` is used in this context because the atomic value is both fetched and updated at the same time. `relaxed` is a memory-ordering specifying that this value can be updated without doing any *flush*. For more information please read [this related part of the specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu105.html#x138-1480002.19.7).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please do tell is there any documentation for openMP as well

Comment: There is only an official [specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf), useful [examples](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-5-0-1.pdf) and a very useful [reference guide](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMPRefCard-5-2-web.pdf).

Comment: @JérômeRichard "only" is maybe slightly mean. There are also many books and a fair amount of online teaching resources. See https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-books/ and https://www.openmp.org/resources/tutorials-articles/ or simply use a search engine.

Comment: @JimCownie The "only" was meant to say there is (AFAIK) no other OpenMP documentation document *directly written by the OpenMP Architecture Review Board* (and mark as such, hence the "official"). I agree the word was unclear/misused. Sure, there are *a lot* of alternative resources on internet and books. Thank you for pointing that out.